Quantum teleportation circuit with rotated measurement
I'm looking at Lattice Surgery on the Raussendorf Lattice, and I am getting confused by one of their teleportation circuits.
In Figure 1, they show the following circuit to achieve MBQC:

It differs from ordinary MBQC circuits in that they measure in the $Z$ basis, as opposed to the X. But one can easily see that this is the same as measuring in the $X$ basis due to the $H$ gate they apply just before measurement, which can be commuted to the end of the circuit, and performs a measurement in the $X$ basis instead. If this is done, it is just the ordinary MBQC circuit.
However the operation they perform on the teleported qubit seems to be wrong. A straightforward calculation shows that:
$$HZ_{\theta}C_{Z}|\psi\rangle\otimes|+\rangle=HZ_{\theta}(\alpha|0\rangle\otimes|+\rangle+\beta|1\rangle\otimes|-\rangle)=H(\alpha|0\rangle\otimes|+\rangle+\beta e^{i\theta}|1\rangle\otimes|-\rangle)\\ =\alpha|+\rangle\otimes|+\rangle+\beta e^{i\theta}|-\rangle\otimes|-\rangle$$
From here, measuring the first qubit in the $Z$ basis, and ignoring normalisation for the moment, will give
$$|0\rangle \otimes \alpha|+\rangle+\beta e^{i\theta}|-\rangle$$
or
$$|1\rangle \otimes \alpha|+\rangle-\beta e^{i\theta}|-\rangle$$
In the first case, when the measurement outcome is +1, you can see this is $|0\rangle \otimes HZ_{\theta}(\alpha|0\rangle+\beta |1\rangle)$, and the byproduct operator has no effect. However, in the case of -1, you don't get $ZHZ_{\theta}|\psi\rangle$, as $$|1\rangle \otimes \alpha|+\rangle-\beta e^{i\theta}|-\rangle=|1\rangle \otimes XHZ_{\theta}(\alpha|0\rangle+\beta |1\rangle)$$
All the byproduct operator $Z^{m}$ would do, if included, is flip the bits.
So what am I missing here? Am I wrong or is this a mistake in the paper? I'll also point out that the equivalent action of measuring in the $X$ basis instead, which, up to a certain operation, would give the same, does give a $Z$ byproduct operator, but before the hadamard, which when rearranged achieves the same operation as the one I arrive at.
Shouldn't it be $$|1\rangle \otimes X^{m}HZ_{\theta}(\alpha|0\rangle+\beta |1\rangle)$$ or, in the original MBQC circuit, $$|1\rangle \otimes HZ^{m}Z_{\theta}(\alpha|0\rangle+\beta |1\rangle)$$

It very well could be a mistake. I think the more important thing is, it doesn't really matter.  MBQC can be ran with the state $X^x Z^z |\psi\rangle $ where we can keep track of $x,z$ throughout the computation.
Future angles are then modified to give the correct angles when commuting through the unwanted $X,Z$ terms. This is simple since $HX = ZH$ and $ Z_\theta X = XZ_{-\theta}$.
Measurements are not an issue either, $Z$ terms don't affect the amplitudes (only phases) so we have the same distribution, and $X$ only moves around the labels for measurements and we can just move them back afterwards.

Actually assuming we are using $Z^{m}$ instead of $X^{m}$ has a huge effect on the implemented operation. We need to do adaptive measurements. Those are performed based on the commutation of the bi-product operators through the circuit. If you get the measurement results, and then assume you are performing one pauli operation instead of another, you would be doing the wrong adaptive measurements due to the assumption of the wrong operators having their angle negated.

A simple example is $$X^{s^{4}}HR_{Z}(A)X^{s^{3}}HR_{Z}(B)X^{s^{2}}HR_{Z}(C)X^{s^{1}}H |\psi\rangle\=X^{s^{4}+s^{2}}Z^{s^{1}+s^{3}}R_{x}(-A)R_{z}(-B)R_{x}(-C)|\psi\rangle$$ which means you'd need to correct the measurement angles as follows $$M(-A(-1)^{s^{1}+s^{3}}) M(-B(-1)^{s^{2}})M(-C(-1)^{s^{1}})$$

Now if you assume $Z^{m}$ instead, you get $$Z^{s^{4}+s^{2}}X^{s^{1}+s^{3}}R_{x}(-A)R_{z}(-B)R_{x}(C)|\psi\rangle$$ but the adaptive measurements now take the form $$M(-A(-1)^{s^{2}}) M(-B(-1)^{s^{1}})M(-C)$$

As can be seen, the order of bi-product operations is different, as is there dependency on the measurement results. Additionally, and more importantly, the adaptive measurements depend on completely different measurement outcomes, or in some cases don't depend on any at all now. So there is a very large effect of using $Z^{m}$ as opposed to $X^{m}$. Yes, you can still do computation by using $Z^{m}$, but you can't do it using the scheme of cluster states and measurements shown here.

My point was, it doesn't matter since a very similar strategy could be used and other than a few terms and signs changing, nothing about the contribution of the work would be lost.

Yes, I agreed with you on that. But since this is computation by cluster states, calling it a mistake is reasonable. You don't perform the computation they describe using the MBQC setup shown, hence my question on whether I had made an error working out the gates. If you assumed you were, and then corrected measurements based on their implementation, you'd get a completely wrong computation.
